# How to fix IN ARRAY_LITERAL, An Array Literal was missing values for one or more rows

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

i am trying to combine sheets in one tab, but getting an error in tab 'final' in A2.
Do you know how this can be fixed?

here's the formula:

```
=query({'00 Account'!A2:I;'01 Brand'!A2:I,'02 NonBrand'!A2:I,'03 Brand EMEA'!A2:I,'04 Brand APAC'!A2:I,'05 Brand ROW'!A2:I,'06 Brand NAMER'!A2:I,'07 ImprShare -NonBrand EMEA'!A2:I,'08 ImprShare -NonBrand APAC'!A2:I,'09 ImprShare -NonBrand ROW'!A2:I,'10 ImprShare -NonBrand NAMER'!A2:I,'11 ImprShare - NAMER'!A2:I,'12 ImprShare - APAC'!A2:I,'13 ImprShare - ROW'!A2:I,'14 ImprShare - EMEA'!A2:I},"Select * where Col1 is not null")
```

Please see link to sheet:https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1RSoS55esM-OTkvqVVBcSeca4Y2F_PVKWlBop6I81qdg/edit#gid=525987131

thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
=query({'00 Account'!A2:I2;
        '01 Brand'!A2:I;'02 NonBrand'!A2:I;
        '03 Brand EMEA'!A2:I;'04 Brand APAC'!A2:I;
        '05 Brand ROW'!A2:I;'06 Brand NAMER'!A2:I;
        '07 ImprShare -NonBrand EMEA'!A2:I;'08 ImprShare -NonBrand APAC'!A2:I;
        '09 ImprShare -NonBrand ROW'!A2:I;'10 ImprShare -NonBrand NAMER'!A2:I;
        '11 ImprShare - NAMER'!A2:I;'12 ImprShare - APAC'!A2:I;
        '13 ImprShare - ROW'!A2:I;'14 ImprShare - EMEA'!A2:I}," select * where Col2 is not null ")
```

Use a `;` instead of a `,` to stack vertically

Comment: ah i didn't notice the comma! thank you so much